# Why event hubs post request contains multiple content types?

Tags: http-post, content-type, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to make a post request to an event hub instance according to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

```
POST https://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<yourentity>/messages
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<yourentity>&sig=<yoursignature from code above>&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName
ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
```

It seems to have two fields of content types. I'm not quite experienced with HTTP protocol but as far as I know the Content-Type entity header is used to indicate the media type of the resource. One post request can have multiple content types using `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;` 
What is the purpose of using the above statements Content-Type and  ContentType?
And why the same post request in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/event-hubs-runtime-rest contains only Content-Type field?

```
POST https://your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/your-event-hub/messages? 
timeout=60&api-version=2014-01 HTTP/1.1  
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net&sig=tYu8qdH563Pc96Lky0SFs5PhbGnljF7mLYQwCZmk9M0%3d&se=1403736877&skn=RootManageSharedAccessKey  
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8  
Host: your-namespace.servicebus.windows.net  
BrokerProperties: {"PartitionKey": "32119834-65f3-48c1-b366-619df2e4c400"}  

{ "DeviceId":"dev-01", "Temperature":"37.0" }
```